# How to format Brazilian phone numbers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-cell-format

I have two possible phone numbers:

One with 9 digits (mobile) and 8 digits (landline), and I need to insert `-` after 4 or 5 digits so they appear as `0000-0000` when 8 digits, and `00000-0000` when they are 9 digits.

Also, need to get a country and state codes like this `+00 (00)` the numbers inside the parentheses are the state codes.

I managed to get a formula that works with one or another, but not both. Can anyone help?

`"+"?? (##) ????-????` > Works for 8 digit numbers

`"+"## (##) ?????-????` > Works with 9 digits.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
=IF(AND(A1>9999999;  A1<=99999999);  "+"&"55"&" ("&"00"&") "&LEFT(A1;4)&"-"&RIGHT(A1;4);
 IF(AND(A1>99999999; A1<=999999999); "+"&"55"&" ("&"00"&") "&LEFT(A1;5)&"-"&RIGHT(A1;4);
 ))
```

and then `"00"` / `"55"` can be referenced from a cell for ultimate comfort

Comment: How to use this formula? Sorry I don't get it

Comment: @Freedo simply put your brazilian phone number in A1 cell and then this formula in B1 cell. formula checks if the number is 8 digit long or 9 digit long and then based on that it will add stuff you requested

Comment: @Freedo >> if A1 is number larger then 9999999 and smaller or equal to 99999999 (eg. all 8 digit possibilities you can ever have), then add `"+"` followed by `"55"` followed by `" ("` followed by `"00"` followed by `") "` followed by 8 digit number separated in the middle with `"-"` (eg 4 digits from left side of the number from A1 cell and 4 digits from right side of the number from A1 cell)